# Cannot get matplotlib to work on M1 mac

Tags: command-line, python

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 161, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 82, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/danielbak/venvs/hw-ble-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

I am using the native mac terminal and python 3.9. I can't use Conda for this circumstance. I've managed to get numpy and lxml working but not matplotlib. I've tried `ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64" pip install matplotlib --compile --no-cache-dir`  and various other solutions but have made no progress. Is this not possible?

Comment: Remove it and install it again from a Terminal not running under Rosetta.